# Firefox can't parse JSON string in jQuery AJAX response

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, firefox

I am experiencing a strange problem while trying to parse JSON strings in jQuery AJAX response. Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Save",
    data: {
        expiry: expiry,
        settings: settings
    }
}).done(function (msg) {
    alert(msg);
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
    if (obj.status == "done") {
        window.location = obj.redirect;
    }
});
```

On IE, Chrome, and Safari, I am getting JSON string in alert, but on Firefox, I am getting

`[obj XMLDocument]`

in the alert.

Here is FF console:

[image]

**obj is null**, but I can see the response JSON string in the console under text attribute

```
responses=Object { xml=document, text="{"status":"done","redir...ippetImage\/s\/6abb68"}
```

Any reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem was on servlet side. I had to set contentType  to make it work.

```
response.setContentType("text/JSON");
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not a valid JSON string. A JSON string is, for all intents and purposes, simply the right-hand side of an assignment in JS.

e.g.

```
var x = 7;
        ^
var y = [1,2,3];
        ^^^^^^^
var z = {a:'b', c: 'd'};
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The parts indicated by `^` correspond to what you'd get if you converted the x/y/z vars to JSON strings.

If you can't write your json string as a JS assignment, e.g.

```
var x = ...json_string_here...;
```

then it's not valid JSON. Your snippet boils down to:

```
var x = responses=Object { .... }
```

which is a syntax error.

Comment: Coincidence probably. The fact that it works on other browsers doesn mean it's proper JSoN.

Comment: `{"status":"done","redirect":"some_url"}` is their any problem with this json string ?

Comment: `response=Object {...}` is Firebug's way of printing an object. You have misapprehended the question (and also the JSON spec: `{a:'b', c: 'd'}` is not valid JSON, `{"a":"b", "c": "d"}` is)